# Set minimum (maximum) Y for DialogFragment

Tags: android

I have a `DialogFragment` that is used both as a standalone fragment hosted in a single activity (for phones) and as a dialog (in tablets).

This fragment has a header layout (title bar) that allows users to close the dialog or so other action bar like activities which is only visible when shown in a dialog.

The fragment also contains an `EditText` component that allows the user to write a potential multiline comment.

The problem I'm facing is that when the user types in the edit text using the soft keyboard, when there's a new line inserted, the entire layout is shifted up which eventually results in a hidden title bar.

What I would like to do is to set a minimum 'Y' value that the dialog fragment can be pushed up to and after that, the dialog remains stationary and the scrolling instead happens in the edit text itself and does not push the entire layout up.

I am at work now so unfortunately I can't paste any code for this layout but it's a simple relative layout with a couple of edit texts, with the second edit text allowing multiline.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Create your xml and define the margins/paddings to the main layout. It will save your efforts and keep the margin/padding values to dimen files, change them according to the screen.

Comment: that's not the problem. I already have my own xml with my own margins and paddings but the entire dialog gets pushed up with my layout inside it. No margin or padding will save me here. I need the dialog itself (containing the layout) not to be pushed up beyond a threshold.